# Edit PATH variable in a shell script to remove specific enteries

Tags: shell

I want to remove from the path environment variable all of the enteries that contain a certain word, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```bash
export PATH=$(echo $PATH | awk -F : 'BEGIN{ORS=":"}{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i !~ /local/) print $i}' | sed 's/.$//')
```

Will exclude all the `$PATH` entries which contain the word "local".

Answer (score 0):

With zsh, where `$PATH` is mapped to the `$path` array like in csh:

```
path=( ${path:#*word*} )
```